# Get a data with HTMLagilitypack from a table with same class

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to catch a data from a website using HTMLAgilityPack. The data is store in a Table but the problem is that there is more than a TD tag with a same class and I don't know how to filter them in a separated fields.

here is what I talking about :

```
<td class="first even">
    Phone number:
</td>
<td class="even">
    06522366154
</td>

<td class="first even">
    Mobile Number:
</td>
<td class="even">
    09163524712
</td>

<td class="first even">
    Email:
</td>
<td class="even">
    h.ghaletaki@gmail.com
</td>
```

in this HTML code, Mobile phone starts with "09xxxx" and Phone Number starts with "0xxx" and you know about emails. I used below code in C# and I catch all the values mixed.

```
 HtmlNodeCollection nodes1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='even']");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `starts-with` to do the prefix check (does the phone number start with zero?) and you might check using `contains` for the `@` in the mail address.

```
//td[@class = 'even' and (starts-with(normalize-space(.), '0') or contains(., '@'))]
```

XPath 1.0 has no support for regular expressions. You might better do the string manipulation and verification outside XPath in C#.